# Cascade copy in oracle

Tags: oracle, copy, cascade, toad

I would like to make a cascade copy. I have a MODEL and the specification of this MODEL is stored in 4 tables and one MODEL is identificated by MODEL_ID in the tables. The MODEL_ID of the MODEL is primary key and the MODEL_ID is increased one by adding new MODEL.

How can I make the MODEL's copy?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. You want to copy a set of rows from some tables with a shared PK, and replace with a new PK value? Please read this on how to ask a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask .

Comment: Yes, I want to copy a set of rows from some tables with a shared PK, and replace with a new PK value.

Comment: Then you need to create a script to generate a new PK, read the existing rows from the 4 tables, and do an insert with the new PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have to copy a model identified by MODEL_ID=`old_model_id` first of all you have to create a new MODEL_ID (for example stored in a variable called `new_model_id`), for example using a sequence (called `SEQ_ID_MODEL` in below code, but you could use another technique to create a new ID).

Then you have to write an insert command for each of the 4 tables retrieving the model to copy with the old id (`old_model_id`) and inserting using the new one(`new_model_id`):

```
PROCEDURE P_COPY_MODEL
(
  old_model_id  IN NUMBER
)IS

new_model_id number;

begin
    select SEQ_ID_MODEL.nextval into new_model_id from dual;

    insert into table1(MODEL_ID, COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N) 
    select (new_model_id, COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N)
    from table1 where MODEL_ID = old_model_id;

    insert into table2(MODEL_ID, COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_M) 
    select (new_model_id, COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_M)
    from table2 where MODEL_ID = old_model_id;

    --and so on for table3 and table4

end;
```

Comment: if I have another variable,  what I use to select correctly the model, what I want to copy, how can I give string value to this variable, I tried this:
Modulation VARCHAR2(8 BYTE);
Modulation := '32QAM';
but this didnot work...can you check that?

Comment: @user2342549 Do you mean for declaring and setting a new variable? Correct syntax should be: `Modulation VARCHAR2(8); Modulation := '32QAM';` Remember to put variable declaration (instruction  `Modulation VARCHAR2(8);`) between `IS` and `BEGIN` keywords at the beginning of the stored procedure

Comment: yes, but I got error and the new model isn't created, the warning message: 
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
4/26    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
          := . ) , @ % default character
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Comment: and how can i give value for old_model_id?